# Which Dimensions and Metrics of Google Ad Manager account should be selected?

Tags: report, google-ad-manager

I am trying to create a report in Google Ad Manager account which can record all the ads of all the advertisers in a given website

I am not sure which dimensions and metrics should be selected in the Ad Manager account for generating this type of report

Taken help from this but didn't find anything relevant https://support.google.com/admanager/table/7531695?hl=en

Any help/suggestion will be highly appreciated.TIA

Answer (score 1):

here are the steps that will help you generate a report in the Google Ad Manager:

1. Go to the **Home page** and select **Reporting**. Click on **New report**.
2. Name the report and scroll down to **Dimensions**. Here, select **Delivery** and then **Advertisers**.
3. Then, scroll down to **Metrics**, and select the metrics you want to view. You can select multiple metrics at once such as Impressions, Revenue, Clicks, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In order to list all the ads of all the advertisers in a given website, you can select :

1. DIMENSIONS

   - ad units
   - advertisers
   - orders
   - line items
2. STATISTICS

   - Impressions

You can also add filters on ad units if you need to get data for a specific site.

Hope this helps.